Foreign film involving a woman searching for her MIA husband
The movie involves a girl who is searching for a man (may or not be her husband at the time) who went missing during the war (world war 2 i think). She visits the different people who knew him for information. One man tells a story of a bomb hitting a hospital.
In the end she finds the man but he suffers from amnesia so he doesn't remember who she is. I think she may also play the tuba. Sorry for the vague description, my memory is a little hazy!

Sounds like A Very Long Engagement from 2004 with Audrey Tautou. From IMDb:

As World War I draws to an end, a young French woman's greatest fight is about to begin. Mathilde has received word that her fiancé Manech is one of five wounded soldiers who have been court-martialed and pushed out into the no-man's land between the French and German armies... an almost certain death. Unwilling to accept that her beloved Manech is lost to her forever, Mathilde embarks on a extraordinary journey to discover the fate of her lover. At each turn, she receives a different heartbreaking variation on how Manech must have spent those last days, those last moments. Still, she never gets discouraged.

When she finally finds him, he has amnesia. She also plays the tuba. You can also see a hospital (containing a zeppelin) being bombed in this page. Here's the trailer:



